# How to configure MassTransit.RuntimeServices to autogenerate the subscriptions database?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, masstransit

I would like that the database used by Masstransit's subscription service was automatically created if it does not exist on the first access.

I know very little about NHibernate and couldn't work this out myself. In Entity Framework it is trivial to configure the database autogeneration, but [there seems to be no EF integration with MT yet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/_blzCHZ9WmI). I found [some code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5885189/1946412) that would probably work if I was dealing directly with NHibernate, but I don't know where I'm supposed to put this code so that it would work with the extra abstraction layer created for MassTransit.

This is my container registration for the sessionfactory required by MT:

```
.RegisterType<ISessionFactory>
  (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
   new InjectionFactory(_context => new NHibernateSessionFactoryProvider(new[]
                                    {
                                        typeof (SubscriptionSagaMap),
                                        typeof (SubscriptionClientSagaMap)
                                    }).GetSessionFactory()))
```

I tried messing around with parameters of the second `NHibernateSessionFactoryProvider` constructor to no avail. Whatever I do, I always get this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: 
>   "Failed to create session factory"
>
> InnerException: 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
>   "Cannot open
>   database "DbTest" requested by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user '[my_user]'."

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to the SQLite provider for NHibernate, or something similar.

There is also a SQL script to setup the database available in the source repository:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/MassTransit.RuntimeServices/SetupSQLServer.sql

It might also be included in the ZIP distribution, I'm not positive. There are many indices that are required, as shown in the script, to ensure the service performs with a large number of subscriptions.

Comment: I'm aware of the scripts that come with the source, but I would like to make this automatic to facilitate deployment. We use wix installers and ideally I would avoid having to create yet another custom action project just to run the scripts against the database. Also, I would like to keep using Sql Server because we already have a few databases and this would make it easier to manage things. So there really is no way to configure auto creation? In EF these indexes could be easily added to the initial configuration. Have you guys made any progress with an EF provider?

Comment: I don't use EF, so I'm not the best person to try and create the saga repository for EF. A pull request would be welcome here by anyone that wants to create one.

Comment: I see. I'll be going on vacation in a few days so I'll consider the possibility of writing my own repository using EF later when I get back. Anyways though, what about support for accessing NHibernate's settings for db autocreation? From the question I linked, I see it's possible to autogenerate the database on NH too, or am I missing something? Wouldn't it just be a matter of 'exposing' it in the NH integration assembly? I suppose this would be much easier than coding the EF repo from the ground up right?

Comment: The session factory supports the adding of arguments, I'm not sure the mappings define all the indices required though. Should be easy enough, I'll consider adding it in the next build to see if it works. Can you enter an issue at https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit so it is tracked?

Comment: I've opened the issue there as you asked. I'll be watching closelly on the next releases for this. Thanks a lot for the support Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way

```
container = new UnityContainer();
        MassTransit.Log4NetIntegration.Logging.Log4NetLogger.Use();

        // Register the ServiceBus to our container.
        container.RegisterInstance<IServiceBus>(ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/Mt_Msmq_Saga_Unity");
            sbc.SetConcurrentConsumerLimit(100);
            sbc.UseControlBus();
            sbc.SetCreateMissingQueues(true);
            sbc.SetPurgeOnStartup(true);
            //sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();

            sbc.Subscribe(subs =>
            {
                subs.LoadFrom(container);
                subs.Saga<RfqSubmittedSaga>(new NHibernateSagaRepository<RfqSubmittedSaga>(Fluently
                    .Configure()
                    .Database(
                        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                            .AdoNetBatchSize(100)
                            .ConnectionString(s => s.Is("Server=192.168.0.2\\SQL2012EXP;initial catalog=MTSaga; User Id=sa; Password=mypassword;"))
                            .DefaultSchema("dbo")
                            .Raw(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Isolation, IsolationLevel.Serializable.ToString()))
                    .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate")
                    .Mappings(m =>
                    {
                        // Tell Fluent NHibernate about our mapping to store the Saga.
                        m.FluentMappings.Add<RfqSubmittedSagaMap>();
                    })
                    .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaUpdate(c).Execute(false, true))
                    .BuildSessionFactory())).Permanent();
            });
        }));
```