# Nhibernate.AspNet.Identity Create the necessary tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use this gigantic bloated monster of a library, Identity, but I don't want to use entity framework. So I got NHibernate.AspNet.Identity!

I think I'm almost athe point of getting it to work but I can't seem to figure out how to generate the schema for the DB.

I thought it would automatically populate the DB with tables on first run. I was wrong...

Does anyone know where I can generate/find the schema for the database? Thanks!

Comment: Put on hold as too broad? Have the closer read only the last sentence? It looks quite narrow to me instead, without a lot of distinct solutions. This is not about generating schema in general, this is about the schema required by a specific tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `SchemaExport` or `SchemaUpdate` (supports migration) classes from `NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl`? You may find usage example at [What is schemaExport in Fluent NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736546/what-is-schemaexport-in-fluent-nhibernate) and [Fluent NHibernate - Create database schema only if not existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884359/fluent-nhibernate-create-database-schema-only-if-not-existing)

In a nutshell the code for FluentNHibernate looks something like (and is similar for XML-based configuartion)

```cs
Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(/* configure database */)
  .Mappings(/* mappings */)
  .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => { new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true); });
```

Comment: Great thank you, the confusion was from my forgetting how to generate a schema fluently!